# How do I grant a user access to Stackdriver Error Reporting in my GCP project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-error-reporting

I can access Error Reporting (https://console.cloud.google.com/errors), but haven't found the right IAM role to assign to a different user to enable that user's access. Documentation is also silent on this. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

*[updated answer]* IAM (Identity and Access Management) is now available for Error Reporting, please refer to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/iam) to learn more.

(I am Product Manager on Stackdriver)

Comment: thanks, we'll use Project Viewer for now, but having more granularity would be useful

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. IAM roles for Error Reporting are currently in the work.

Comment: In order to be able to see the IAM roles you need to enable the "Stackdriver Error Reporting API" API.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Indeed Error Reporting IAM has launched, however, the fact that the API needs to be enabled to see it in the IAM list is not working as intended. I will follow up internally.

Comment: the documentation has been published: https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/iam let me update my answer again